# How to take out individual data from a returned database?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm returning data from a database which looks something like this:

```
for data in enumerate(self.Admin_Database.Get_Admin_Users()):
    print data
```

I'm getting the output `(9, (12345, 'Admin', 'Password'))` which is what I want but I'm struggling to get individual indexes from this data. For example if I were to do `data[2]` I would get the error `tuple index out of range` instead of getting `Admin`.

Is there a simple way to get the individual data?

Comment: data[0] would be 9 and data[1] would be (12345, 'Admin', 'Password'); so try data[1][1] to get 'Admin'

Comment: @KBN ya i forgot it was two tuples lol, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *nested* tuple. Think of it like this:

```
data = (9, (12345, 'Admin', 'Password'))
data[0] = 9
data[1] = (12345, 'Admin', 'Password')
data[1][0] = 12345
data[1][1] = 'Admin'
data[1][2] = 'Password'
```

Since `data` only contains two elements (those being `9` and the tuple), trying to access index `2` will raise an `IndexError`.